# Sum of random number of Bernoulli

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $T$ be a non-negative, integer valued random variable, and $X_i$ independent Bernoulli s.t.
$P(X_i=0)=p$. Of $T$, I know only that it has mean $\mu$ with $1 \lt \mu \lt \infty$. How do I find the distribution of the random sum $\sum_{n=1}^T X_n$? I know it will be a binomial sum, but how explicit can I be when I don't know the distribution of $T$?

Comment: Bernoulli distributions more usually have $P(X_i=1)=p$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-p$.  If you know the mean and variance of $T$, you can find the mean and variance of $X_1+\cdots+X_T$

Comment: @Karl : it is not clear if you are looking at the distribution of $Z=T+X$ or $Z=T+X_1+X_2+...+X_n$

Comment: Sorry. I am looking at the distribution of X_1+...+X_T

Comment: @Henry. I only know the mean. Is it enough to find the mean of the sum $X_1+\cdots+X_T$? Should it be just the product of the means of $T$ and $X_i$?

Comment: @Karl - yes: the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^T X_i$$

The conditional density $Y|T=t$ is a binomial $Bin(t;q)$ where $q=1-p$.

Thus the pmf of Y (marginal is the following)

$$P(Y=y)=\Sigma_t p_T(t)p_{Y|T}(y|t)$$

---

If one wanted $E(Y)$ he can use the conditional expectation properties

$$E(Y)=E[E(Y|T)]=E[T(1-p)]=(1-p)E(T)=\mu(1-p)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was not clear at all. I edited.

Comment: @Karl _ I edited too....now the question is clear

Comment: And if one wanted the expectation, would one get the products of the expectations of T and $X_i$?

Comment: @Karl : edited with answer... As an exercise you can set $T\sim Pois(\theta)$ and calculate $P(Y=y)$ explicitly